# After function completed, wait 10 seconds then re-run the same function with cancellation

Tags: c#, .net

Sorry I am new to this C# .NET language, there are two doubts I wish to know.

I have the following function bind to `Start` button and when I click the button, below function will run for ONE time.

**Question 1**

How to make the function wait for 10 seconds then re-run after the previous successfully completed. The function should not run if there is any error occurred or user click cancel button.

**Question 2**

How is it possible to cancel the 10 seconds timer if I want the function to completely stop running? *If I want it to run after that I could just press the `Start` button again.*

**Code**

```
private void RunAPI(DBSetting dbSetting, ThreadObj callback)
        {
            ConnectDB();

            Function function = new Function();

            try
            {
                function.A2P_GetCompanyInfo(dbSetting, con);
                //function.P2A_AddARPayment(dbSetting, con);
                function.A2P_AddPaymentMethod(dbSetting, con);

                // AR Invoice & Invoice Detail
                string invoice_dockey = function.A2P_AddInvoice(dbSetting, con);
                function.A2P_AddInvoiceDetail(dbSetting, invoice_dockey, con);

                // AR CN & CN Detail
                string arcn_dockey = function.A2P_AddArcn(dbSetting, con);
                function.A2P_AddARCNDetail(dbSetting, arcn_dockey, con);
                function.A2P_AddARCNKnockOff(dbSetting, arcn_dockey, con);

                // ARPayment & Payment Detail 
                string arpayment_dockey = function.A2P_AddARPayment(dbSetting, con);

                // User 
                function.A2P_AddUser(dbSetting, con);

                // Payment Method 
                function.A2P_AddPaymentMethod(dbSetting, con);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error Message : " + ex.Message);
            }

            DisconnectDB();
        }
```

Comment: You will need to involve both timers and multiple threads if you want to have a wait period that is able to be cancelled.  Since you're new to C#, you may be in a little over your head.  But what you want to use is async/await with a cancellation token.

Comment: tomato sauce with tomato

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is pretty possible to do without using multiple threads. All you need it a boolean flag to indicate if your function run is still needed or it has been cancelled. Here is a sample code, assuming we have two buttons (button1 and button2) and a timer (timer1):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool shouldRunAgain;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Interval = 10000;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        shouldRunAgain = true;
        RunMyFunction();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        shouldRunAgain = false;
    }

    private void RunMyFunction()
    {
        try
        {
            // do something
            timer1.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // handle exceptions
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        if (shouldRunAgain)
        {
            shouldRunAgain = false;
            RunMyFunction();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, the real code would need to handle more situations, like if the user clicks Start twice etc.